# How can I get this many-to-many relationship work in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I am getting an error with a many to many relationship in eloquent in Laravel 5.5

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42000)
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'users' (SQL: select `users`.*, `users`.`roles_id` as `pivot_roles_id`, `users`.`users_id` as `pivot_users_id`, `users`.`id` as `pivot_id`, `users`.`created` as `pivot_created`, `users`.`updated` as `pivot_updated`, `users`.`deleted` as `pivot_deleted` from `users` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `users`.`users_id` where `users`.`roles_id` = 2)

I have a users table, roles table and a user_role table (pivot table). The user_role table has the following columns: id, users_id(fk from users table),roles_id (fk from roles table),created,updated,deleted.

In the User model I have

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\roles::class,'roles','users_id','roles_id','id','id')->withPivot(['id','created','updated','deleted']);
}
```

In the roles model I have

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\User::class,'users','roles_id','users_id','id','id')->withPivot(['id','created','updated','deleted']);
}
```

In my controller I have

```
$roles = $this->rolesObject->whereNull('deleted')->orderBy('role')->get();
//Just for testing how to view the relationship won't be real code in the end
foreach($roles as $role){
    foreach($role->users as $user){
        dump($user->display_name);
    }
}
```

Looking through the documentation and it looks like i am setting up the relationship correctly but obviously I'm not and I have no idea what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to `belongsToMany` method is a relation table name([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)), you have to pass `role_user` rather than `users`.

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\roles::class,'role_user','users_id','roles_id','id','id')->withPivot(['id','created','updated','deleted']);
}

...
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\User::class,'role_user','roles_id','users_id','id','id')->withPivot(['id','created','updated','deleted']);
}
```

Your code thinks that your second parameter `users` is a relation table name, that's the reason of the error.